# Set httpOnly in NewCookie using Jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I want to set httpOnly on a NewCookie created by Jersey.

I am using the following library for Jersey:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

This uses javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1 which doesn't seem to support httpOnly in NewCookie.

Which Jersey library should I use with Tomcat if I want to have a httpOnly cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JAX-RS/Jersey 2.x For that, use the following dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.32</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need support for JSON/POJO mapping, add the following

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.32</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also remove any dependencies you currently are using that are for Jersey 1.x. Leaving them may cause some conflict and cause your app to not work. If you find out you need any other features for Jersey that require other jars, make sure you use the same version.

**Note:** If for any reason, you *must* stick with using Jersey 1.x, a cookie is sent simply by sending a [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header. When the browser sends it back to the server, is in the form of a [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) request header. So you could use cookies without needing the actual `NewCookie` and `Cookie` classes that JAX-RS 2.x offers by simple working with headers. See [Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).